# Zkoss: How to notify user of session timeout or lost connection to server?

Tags: javascript, session, client-side, zk

Is there a way of programmatic checking of session timeout or lost connection when using the zkoss web UI framework? The problem is that even if I shut down the server, redeploy or restart it, the UI will just remain displayed in the browser.

The user will discover that something is wrong only when trying to interact with the UI (e.g. clicks a button). The it either pops up session timeout info or server unreachable info.

What I am looking for is something on the client side that would notify the user right away (or within reasonably short time). Something that, when the session is lost, server goes down or is otherwise inaccessible, will for example show a popup window that  tells the user something is wrong (so he can immediately refresh or take some other action).

I was looking at the docs, but they do not say anything specific for this case. The session settings cover limits, keep-alive to prevent session timeout, but that's it.

I'm considering some custom javascript that would periodically ping the server (maybe a special servlet, that would also let the script know about session timeouts), but I would prefer something native to the zk framework. The zk timer component seems to cease function when the connection is lost, but it does not trigger the error popup.

Comment: should a page witch contains textfield and button be good? You just enter a message, press send and all logged in users get that message?

Comment: Distributing the message is fine. My problem is that when the session timeouts (server goes down), the UI stays the same. If the users wait for the message and just check the screen, they will not see it as the UI is no longer connected to the backend website. The problem I have is that the user does not know of this and a message may have arrived without him knowing. From the user's point of view, all looks fine until he does something actively with the UI (like pressing a button).

Comment: You use pagetemplates?

Comment: No, not yet anyway. I'm quite new to zk, so I'm not so familiar with all the aspects. What I have now is a page that has a timer element. The controller listens for "onTimer" and refreshes some components (mainly listboxes for now).

Answer (score 3):

I'll post tommorow the code how you can distribute a message for all logged in clients.

In mean while, here is code what you can implement to notify the user just before the session timeout is going to activate(not for server restart) :

### SessionTimeOutExecListener.java:

```
public class SessionTimeOutExecListener implements ExecutionInit, UiLifeCycle {

    private String timerId = "timeoutNotifyTimer";

    public void init(Execution exec, Execution parent) throws Exception {

        Timer timer = (Timer) exec.getDesktop().getAttribute(timerId);
        if (timer != null) {

            if (isSendbyMsgBox(timer, exec))
                return;

            timer.stop();
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    private boolean isSendbyMsgBox(Timer timer, Execution exec) {
        HttpServletRequest hreq = (HttpServletRequest)exec.getNativeRequest();

        for (int j = 0;; ++j) {
            final String uuid = hreq.getParameter("uuid_"+j);
            if (uuid == null)
                break;

            if (uuid.equals(timer.getUuid()))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void afterComponentAttached(Component comp, Page page) {
    }

    public void afterComponentDetached(Component comp, Page prevpage) {
    }

    public void afterComponentMoved(Component parent, Component child,
            Component prevparent) {
    }

    public void afterPageAttached(Page page, Desktop desktop) {
         Object obj = desktop.getAttribute(timerId);

        if (obj == null) {

            int tmout = desktop.getWebApp().getConfiguration()
                    .getSessionMaxInactiveInterval();

            final Timer timer = new Timer((tmout - 2) * 1000);

            timer.addEventListener(Events.ON_TIMER, new EventListener() {
                public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {

                    Messagebox.show("Your session are about to be expired",
                        "Information", Messagebox.OK,
                        Messagebox.INFORMATION, new EventListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
                                if (Messagebox.ON_OK.equals(event.getName())){
                                    timer.start();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                }
            });
            timer.setPage(page);
            desktop.setAttribute(timerId, timer);
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    public void afterPageDetached(Page page, Desktop prevdesktop) {
    }

}
```

### zk.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>test.MyExecListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

### Edit:

Like I said, here is the code for sending a message to all **active** sessions.
First a simple page where you can send the message.

### message.zul:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<window xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
            viewModel="@id('vm') @init('be.chillworld.MessageVM')" width="100%" height="100%">
    <textbox value="@bind(vm.message)"/>
    <button onClick="@command('sendMessage')" label="Send"/>
</window>
```

As you can see, it's MVVM but don't worry, you can insert this in a MVC project also because I work with the `EventQueue`

Then we need a listener for **all** pages, so the best practice is to create a abstract VM or extends the Composer you use.

### AbstractVM.java:

```
package be.chillworld;

import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Init;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Event;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.EventListener;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.EventQueues;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.Clients;

/**
 *
 * @author chillworld
 */
public abstract class AbstractVM {

    @Init
    public void abstractInit() {
        EventQueues.lookup("globalMessage", EventQueues.APPLICATION, true).subscribe(new EventListener<Event>() {

            public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
                if ("onSendMessage".equals(event.getName())) {
                    Clients.showNotification(String.valueOf(event.getData()));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So this is actually what we are going to do, when we get the event.
If you want to make a basic composer you can do like this :

### BasicComposer.java:

```
package be.chillworld;

import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Event;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.EventListener;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.EventQueues;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.SelectorComposer;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.Clients;

/**
 *
 * @author chillworld
 */
public class BasicComposer extends SelectorComposer<Component> {

    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        EventQueues.lookup("globalMessage", EventQueues.APPLICATION, true).subscribe(new EventListener<Event>() {

            public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
                if ("onSendMessage".equals(event.getName())) {
                    Clients.showNotification(String.valueOf(event.getData()));
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Don't forget to extend the `BasicComposer` or the `AbstractVM` for each view.
That's why I asked if you work with pagetemplates, if you have a master template for each page you simply could insert it there and every page will have the subscription for the eventlistener, so you didn't have to work with the `BasicComposer` or `AbstractVM`

Oke, now we create the viewmodel for the message.zul.

### MessageVM.java:

```
package be.chillworld;

import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Command;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Init;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Event;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.EventQueues;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.Clients;

/**
 *
 * @author chillworld
 */
public class MessageVM extends AbstractVM {
    private String message;

    @Init(superclass = true)
    public void init(){}

    @Command
    public void sendMessage () {
        if (message==null || message.trim().isEmpty()) {
            Clients.showNotification("Please enter something to send.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("posting event");
            EventQueues.lookup("globalMessage", EventQueues.APPLICATION, true).publish(new Event("onSendMessage", null, message));
        }

    }



    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'll extend the `AbstractVM` but there is **1 part even so important** then just extending it, namely the `@Init`
As you can see I declare again an init method but I say `superclass = true` in the annotation.
 **If we don't do this, the init method from the abstractVM will never be triggered!**

For the BasicComposer it's differtent, If you override the `doAfterCompose` method, you always call `super` so that's always executed.

You can test it with multiple sessions on 1 pc like this :

- Open IE => go to message.zul
- Open IE in private => go to some page who has the subscription of the eventlistener.
- Open FF => same as IE in private.
- Enter a message in the textbox and press send.
- See if all browsers get the message. (If you want to be sure, put `String.valueOf(Sessions.getCurrent())` in the `Clients.showNotification`)

Hope this can help you with your problem.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for such a comprehensive answer! This is much better than constant polling! (Sorry for the delay, I was sick)

Comment: Actually you use the build in serverpush of zk. One of the configurations is polling : http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Server_Push/Configuration.  Hope this could help you in the project